# Rewrite Rule from sub directory web root

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, rewrite

I want to make a one time change to my website URL structure. I want to rewrite URLs from /2015/11/sample-post/ to /sample-post/  -  I don't care about the existential dilemmas caused by such a decision, I only want to know how to accomplish the result. This is for a low traffic site redirection, and not concerned about performance hits on the referring server.

How could I accomplish that?

Comment: Posted my question to the WP site and they only want to solve this with a WP solution. I'm trying to abandon the WP install on referring site and only implement the solution using Rewrite rules so I don't have to Admin a WP site I no longer want or need. Hence, Apache/Linux/Rewrite is the correct way to obtain a solution for my issue.

Comment: Steve, please don't post duplicate questions. Michael referred you to our canonical QA about rewrite rules. Trust me, if you spend some good time reading through that QA, you'll have enough of an understanding to take a hack at this yourself. We don't do handouts, we expect that people have put effort into solving their own problem before coming here. So...give it a try and then come back here with any specific, well-researched questions you may have.

Comment: EEAA, implied that same exact question has been asked before, which it has not.  The canonical QA about rewrite rules does nothing that Google Search can do for me, so if I cannot get specific advice or help with a problem, why should I even be using your site?  I gave it a try, and explained why my challenge is different, reading the canonical QA did nothing to address my specific need.

Comment: You dropped a problem in our laps and said, "Here, solve this." We are very much willing to help, but we require that question-askers show evidence of working in the problem themselves. If you've tried rewrite rules, edit your original question with them and explain what's working, what's not working, etc. When you edit your question, it will automatically be entered into a re-open review queue where your peers can vote to re-open (if you've shown ample due diligence) or to not re-open.

Comment: I've tried many different variations of Rewrite rules which I am not willing to post here because they contain sensitive information.  For example:  #RewriteRule "^/2015/11/(.+)" "http://www.domain.com/$1" [R=301,R,L]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$ http://www.domain.com/$3
First time here, and getting nothing but grumpy characters telling me I don't know how to ask a question.  Show me which paragraph your canonical answer addressed my issue, I'd believe you were doing more than brushing me off.  I'm not a sysadmin by trade that is why I looked to you guys for help.

Comment: You guys are way to smart for your own good.  Question answered by friendly folks over at Stack Exchange without any harassment.  My overall experience with you guys has been poor and will not recommend you in the future.  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208761/rewrite-url-to-remap-wordpress-permalink/208766

Comment: 1) there was absolutely no harassment. If there had been, the people responsible would be suspended. 2) What did happen was us trying to help you understand what our [expectations](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) are as a community. Each SE site is truly its own community, with their own rules and expectations. 3) If wp.SE wants to give handouts, that's up to them. We've just chosen to have a different standard of participation. I'm glad you got your question answered.